# Why Object() != Object() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So the question is that two same objects are not equal in JavaScript, let's say:

```
Object() == Object()
```

or even:

```
[{a: 1}, {a: 2}].indexOf({a: 1}); //returns -1 not found
```

What's the reason of this strange behavior?

Comment: Those are two similar objects, they certainly are not the same.

Comment: Maybe that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects/16788517

Comment: @Musa any more clues?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani There isn't a predefined way to determine the *similarity* or "*deep equality*" of 2 objects -- e.g., they both only have 1 property, `a`, with the same value, `1`. Though, some libraries, such as Underscore, do define functions for this purpose.

Comment: What's the reason of this strange question ?

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer came from Python, that seems a strange behavior to me.

Comment: According to https://osrc.dfm.io/afshinm/ you are in the top 10% most active JavaScript users on github, but you come here with a question like this. I find that really confusing. But props for learning I guess..

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer the reason for this strange question is this strange tweet https://twitter.com/afshinmeh/status/506500753251651584 ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects are compared by reference. And two references are equal only if they point to the same object.

Comment: Is that a correct behavior? Do we have the same behavior in other languages such as Python?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani yep. in Python ``The "is" operator tests object identity. Python tests whether the two are really the same object (i.e., live at the same address in memory).``

Comment: To prevent confusion: In JS You might stumble on `Object.is`, which will also test for identity on objects, only strict, and not broken like `===`...

Answer (score 2):

Objects are reference and when you compare two reference they return false.

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)(given by Eamon Nerbonne) here has a very relevant point:

> Objects are considered equivalent when
>
> - They are exactly equal per `===` (String and Number are unwrapped first to ensure `42` is equivalent to `Number(42)`)
> - or they are both dates and have the same `valueOf()`
> - or they are both of the same type and not null and...
>
>   - they are not objects and are equal per `==` (catches numbers/strings/booleans)
>   - or, ignoring properties with `undefined` value they have the same properties all of which are considered recursively equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Same applies for Arrays 

`([] === []) //returns false`

And NaN is a special value as well which is never equal to itself.

`NaN === NaN  //False`